# Login screen corrupted ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login, screen

I was checking different monitor resolutions, and one came up garbage, so I just waited for the revert time-out, and everything was fine, I set it back to its original. But, now the login screen is completely corrupted; the only reason I can use the system is I had auto login set up. Somehow the resolution of the login screen got changed and I cannot fix it. I tried installing lightdm, but it has the same problem. I also tried re-installing gdm3, but that did not fix it. Somewhere there is a corrupted configuration file. Any ideas how I can get the original screen back?

Edit: Sorry I forgot some important details. This is ubuntu 20.04 server edition for raspberry pi, with ubuntu-desktop installed. The system is a raspberry-pi 4b 8gb. The monitor is an older vga 1024x768.  I have not tried to do any configuring for the login screen, I have not edited any of its files (at least not intentionally).